# Broken Oven Keypad

Tags: c++

> The keypad is broken so the input numbers 1, 4, and 7 aren't working. In turn the computer outputs the next lowest and next highest number where 1, 4, and 7 are none of the digits.

My goal is to check out the digits and output true using a boolean function and then output the next highest number and next lowest number. I'm pretty sure I did most of what I need to do, but it isn't working out. 
I have inputted the number 444, and the results that came out were 443, and 445.
Thank you for your help.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <cmath>

using namespace std;

bool containDigit(int number, int digit);

int main()
{
    int number, digit, lowNum, highNum;

cout<<"Enter a number between 1 and 999 for the oven temperature: ";
cin>>number;

//1st digit
digit = number / 100;
containDigit(number, digit);
if (containDigit(number, digit) == true)
{
    number = number - 100;
}

//2nd digit
digit = (number / 10) % 10;
containDigit(number, digit);
if (containDigit(number, digit) == true)
{
    number = number - 10;
}

//3rd Digit
digit = number % 10;
containDigit(number, digit);
if (containDigit(number, digit) == true)
{
    number = number - 1;
}

cout<<number<<endl;


getche();
return 0;

}

bool containDigit(int number, int digit)
{
    if ((digit == 1) || (digit == 4) || (digit == 7))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what's going wrong? A specific problem you're facing?

Comment: You'll want to get in the habit of specifying your issues in more detail. How do you know it's not working? What kind of results are you seeing?

Comment: Also: I appreciate your honesty in specifying the `homework` tag, but [you don't have to do that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this looks like homework, I will refrain from doing it for you and give you these hints:

It looks like you're not really clear on what "1st digit" is. Is it the first one from the left (hundreds) or the right (ones)? Look at your code and tell yourself how each portion of it would answer my question.

Is it ever possible for `lowNum` or `highNum` to have more than one digit different than `number` with your code as it is? How? Where are `lowNum` and `highNum` changed, and how?

Also, to expand on what @Al Kepp has said: When you have a function like that, try to test it with some very simple inputs rather than straight out assuming it works. This is called (or is similar to) "unit testing", which dictates that you divide your program into simple, independent units and test them separately. A simple call like `containDigit(999, 4)` returning `true` would've rang warning bells.

And speaking of warnings, always, *always* compile with as many of them as you can stand. (e.g. `-Wall` for `gcc`) Doing such might've warned you of the fact that you're not using the parameter `number` inside `containDigit` at all.

Comment: The first digit the left-most digit and the middle the second, etc.
It is impossible for lowNum and highNum to have more than one digit different than number, but I can't find the problem. I know that's what's preventing my program from working and I've been breaking my head for awhile. lowNum and highNum are changed in the main function  by decreasing or increasing by whatever the digit is. I got the program to work if I replaced the `lowNum = number - 100;
  highNum = number + 100;` code with just `number = number - (10*(WHATEVER DIGIT PLACE IT'S IN))`

Comment: I inputted 444 and got 333, which is valid. But, I can't seem to get it to work with lowNum and highNum.

Comment: Look at the "1st digit" part. Which digit does it check? Which digit does it change?

Comment: How did you get 333? I'm getting 443. Update the code in the question body?

Comment: No problem. Nonetheless, I think I'm approaching this problem incorrectly and instead I'm supposed to do two loops, one that goes backwards and one that goes forward until the bool function doesn't return true and then it returns the higher number as highNum and the lower number as lowNum.

Comment: I rather think you can solve the problem one digit at a time. Admittedly, I haven't given the problem as much thought as you have, but what's wrong with having "2nd digit" work on the result of "1st digit" instead of the original number once again?

Comment: That's a good idea, I didn't think about it. I never tried it. But, I don't even have a base program right now haha.

Comment: It's rather close to the answer; I think it would work once you fixed `containDigit` and did what I just said.

Comment: I think you're right, I've been on this problem for so long I don't know what's right anymore haha. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The bug is in containDigit function. Try this:

```
bool containDigit(int number, int digit) {
    if(digit == 1 || digit == 4 || digit == 7) return true;
    return false;
}
```

You must use `==` instead of `=`.
Also you actually don't need `number` argument there.

Also there can be done several optimizations. Please look at it yourself (it's your homework) and think about repeated code.

Comment: There is also the problem that the function does not return a value if the condition is not true. This means that _anything_ could be returned, sometimes it may be "true" sometimes "false". If the function shouldn't do anything else I suggest changing to `return (digit == 1 || digit == 4 || digit == 7);`.

Comment: J.P. You are right. Corrected. (I put it on two lines, because that way it is better readable for beginners.)

Comment: I changed my code to
    `if ((digit == 1) || (digit == 4) || (digit == 7))
    {
        return true;
    else 
    {
            return 0;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Your function containDigit has two problems:

1. It shouldn't need to receive the variable "number" as it doesn't use it
2. You want to compare with == not =